# question on sentence creation

Tags: exam-questions

> Peter is registering a case in a Police station against his neighbour.
>
> Peter is registering a case against his neighbor in a Police Station.

now what is the differences on the above sentences.please explain.

Comment: Please add more detail to this question to explain why you think there is a difference, and what that difference might be.   Hint -- there is no difference.

Comment: i missed to put the auxiliary verb. i meant that Peter is in a Police station and making FIR(First Investigation Report) against his Neighbour so my concerned is that which position is appropriate in a sentence either Place "in a police station or against Neighbour.

Comment: They both sound a little stilted to me. A version I would use (which also means the same thing) is: *Peter's in a police station, registering a complaint against his neighbour.*

Answer (score 1):

The two examples in the edited question have exactly the samke meaning. Both are grammatically valid. There is no obvious grammatical reason to favor either over the other.